# In Crystal report how to move grouped values depending on field value?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I have a situation when I need to move grouped part in the bottom depending on value. A little explanation:

I have a grouped values that looks something like this:

```
Name:
  Jossy
Name: Ascense
  Bill
Name: Beser
  Alase
```

As you can see, it is grouped by name BUT because I can have a situation when name is string empty, Crystal Report are placing it at the top. What I need to do is to move grouped part to bottom in case Name is empty, so it will be like this:

```
Name: Ascense
  Bill
Name: Beser
  Alase
Name:
  Jossy
```

I tried to do this in specific order, but this thing for some reason started to cut down a part of values.

How can I accomplish this in crystal report?

Answer (score 1):

Like all great things in life, you can pull this off by cheating. Make *another* Group just above your current Name Group. Group based on this formula:

```
ISNULL({YourNameField}) OR {YourNameField} = ""
```

Hide its Headers and Footers and sort by *Descending*. (...unless I have that backwards and you need *Ascending*...) This will make the blank ones appear after all the others, no fuss.

Comment: Honestly not sure why exactly it supposed to work. Basically, it will sort already sorted list or what?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko It splits your data into 2 piles: Those with `Names` and those without. Then you just arrange those 2 piles such that the nameless ones come after the named ones.

Comment: Can't it be applied for main group? Or this formula will simply disable default ascending sorting?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Because you add it *above* your main group, the alphabetical sorting still applies to the `Named` section. Just trust me on this, try it out and you'll see.

Comment: Well, I'd like to try, but honestly, I have no idea where exactly. "Use a formula as group Sort Order" or somewhere else. If this one is correct, then issue is formula doesn't recognize field.

Comment: @OlegsJasjko Start by making the standalone formula itself. Then make a new Group, and when you're setting up that Group. (If you're having issues with the formula, post the formula you wrote and we can debug that.)